# A simple require makes the contract to fail

Tags: truffle, openzeppelin

I have the following contract (truffle + zeppelin):

```
contract SampleCrowdsale is CappedCrowdsale, RefundableCrowdsale {

    uint256 public cirCap;

    function SampleCrowdsale(uint256 _startTime, uint256 _endTime, uint256 _rate, uint256 _goal, uint256 _cap, address _wallet) public
    CappedCrowdsale(_cap)
    FinalizableCrowdsale()
    RefundableCrowdsale(_goal)
    Crowdsale(_startTime, _endTime, _rate, _wallet)
    {
        //As goal needs to be met for a successful crowdsale
        //the value needs to less or equal than a cap which is limit for accepted funds
        require(_goal <= _cap);
        cirCap = getTokenAmount(_cap);
    }

    function createTokenContract() internal returns (MintableToken) {
        return new SampleCrowdsaleToken();
    }

    function airdropCoins(address beneficiary, uint256 cirAmount) onlyOwner public {
        uint256 authorizedCoinsRemaining = cirCap - token.totalSupply();
        require(cirAmount > 0);
        require(cirAmount <= authorizedCoinsRemaining); // <== This fails to deploy !!!
        token.mint(beneficiary, cirAmount);
    }

}
```

Any ideas why the "require(cirAmount <= authorizedCoinsRemaining);" makes the contract to fail with the very cryptic message:

```
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount
```

Comment: How exactly do you know this is this expression that makes the contract fail ?

Comment: What is token.tokenSupply()

Comment: @NicolasMassart This is what gave it away: Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount

Comment: @1sn0s https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/BasicToken.sol

Comment: @NicolasMassart and if I commend this line out, the contract is deployed perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting a gas limit in your truffle config.

For example in `truffle.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      gas: 6721975,
      network_id: 5777
    }
  }
};
```

The gas limit is the default limit provided by ganache or however you're running your local test network.

Comment: I've changed the limit on geth but not on the truffle.js. Thanks